# open a shell tab for each service in a docker compose file

Tags: c++, docker, docker-compose

I have a client-server (both written in C++) application that I am managing using docker-compose. I'm quite new in docker technology and I'm wondering if `docker-compose up` can do the following job for me:

1. run services
2. open a shell tab for each service in the `docker-compose.yml` file.

I need a separate shell for each service because everytime that I change the code (in client or server) I would like to stop the program, re-compile it and re-run. At the moment I use a workaround:

1. run `docker-compose up`
2. run `docker container ls` to find containers id
3. for each container open a shell tab and run `docker exec -it <container-id> /bin/bash`

I'm wondering if there is a more elegant solution. I'm using Ubuntu and this is my `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: '3.1'
services: 
    server:
        build: ./server
        ports: 
            - "3500:3500"
        volumes: 
            - ./server/src:/home/src
            - ./server/bin:/home/bin
        working_dir: /home/src
        stdin_open: true
        tty: true
    client:
        build: ./client
        ports: 
            - "2800:2800"
        volumes: 
            - ./client/src:/home/src
            - ./client/bin:/home/bin
        working_dir: /home/src
        stdin_open: true
        tty: true
    db:
        image: mysql
        command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
        restart: always
        environment:
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: example
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simplify this setup using Docker's native image system.  Typically the instructions for compiling the application will be built into the `Dockerfile`, so running `docker-compose up --build` will recompile things.  Docker's layer cache system makes this run very quickly if the application hasn't actually changed.  Once you have that, you don't need `volumes:` to overwrite the image contents, and you shouldn't separately need an interactive shell attached to each container.

If you remove `volumes:` and some other settings that are either in the `Dockerfile` or that you don't usually need, that leaves you with a much shorter `docker-compose.yml`:

```yaml
version: '3'
services: 
    server:
        build: ./server
        ports: 
            - "3500:3500"
        # volumes: undo what server/Dockerfile does
        # working_dir: is the Dockerfile WORKDIR
        # server-type processes don't usually need stdin_open: or tty:
    client:
        build: ./client
        ports: 
            - "2800:2800"
    db:
        # as above
```

When you change something, you can run `docker-compose up --build -d`, and it will rebuild and restart the specific things that need to be rebuilt and restarted.

There are direct `docker-compose` equivalents to many of the `docker` commands.  If you really need an interactive shell in a container, for example, you can

```sh
docker-compose exec server /bin/sh
```

[`docker-compose exec`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/exec/) will look up the Docker container ID for you, and defaults to the `docker exec -it` flags.

Comment: i do really see the improvment in not using volumes (and in not use tty on server), so you're suggesting to add some COPY, RUN(to compile) and CMD to execute in the Dockerfile and run docker-compose up --build -d when something change right? Create a separate shell tab for each service would still a problem to me, these programs produce a lot of output and i would like to maintain a separate tab for each service. Is there any way to achieve this in one shot or have i to run docker-compose exec for each service?

Comment: `docker-compose logs` will print one service's output; `docker-compose up` (without `-d`) will print all services' outputs together.  (If your services log to files, they'll be easier to manage in Docker if you can reconfigure them to log to stdout instead.)  There's not any direct integration from Docker to multi-tabbed terminals (and I don't think there's really any standard escape sequences for manipulating them; the old DEC CRT terminals didn't have multiple input streams).

Answer (score 0):

Here is my example with Nginx

```
    version: '3'
    services:
        nginx:
            stdin_open: true
            tty: true
            image: nginx        
            ports: 
                - "80:80"
```

Get into the container in interactive mode with `docker-compose run <SERVICE_NAME> sh`. Here is the command for getting into the Nginx container interactive mode

```
docker-compose run nginx sh
```